# What's wrong with this JPA @Query?

Tags: sql, spring, database, jpa, h2

I have a Spring Boot app, using Spring Data JPA in connection with H2 database. I tried to write a `@Query` method in one of my `JpaRepositories`, yet it always returns an empty collection and I don't know why.

```
public interface ProductService extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE category=':category'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> getCategory(@Param("category") String category);
}
```

I've only put this code above because I'm sure the data is present in the database. I've verified it by running this exact same query from H2-console and it works every time. What could be the problem here?

Comment: You don't have to keep the variable annotated with @param inside quotes. Remove the quotess. So the where clause goes like this `where category=:category`

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JPA:

`List<Product> findAllByCategory(String category);`

Using the native query:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM product WHERE category=?1;",nativeQuery=true)
List<Product> getAllByCategory(String category);
```

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM product WHERE category=:category;",nativeQuery=true)
List<Product> getAllByCategory(@Param String category);
```

Personally I'd use the JPA version as you may in future want to use a Spring Paging endpoint so would want to pass in a `Pageable` parameter in to the repo.

`List<Product> findAllByCategory(String category,Pageable page);`

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the way he is passing params. Its the quotes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM product p WHERE p.category=:category", nativeQuery = true)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can try by providing alias for a table and selecting the same alias name instead of * as below

```
@Query(value = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.category = :category")
List<Product> getCategory(@Param("category") String category);
```